# C++ having cin read a return character

Tags: c++, input, return, iostream, cin

I was wondering how to use `cin` so that if the user does not enter in any value and just pushes `ENTER` that `cin` will recognize this as valid input.

Comment: "The C++ Programming Language" by Bjarne Stroustrup certainly thinks that cin will return '\n' but I cant get it to work.  I will just try the getline route.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will probably want to try `std::getline`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string line;
std::getline( std::cin, line );
if( line.empty() ) ...
```

Answer (score 5):

I find that for user input `std::getline` works very well.

You can use it to read a line and just discard what it reads.

The problem with doing things like this,

```
// Read a number:
std::cout << "Enter a number:";
std::cin >> my_double;

std::count << "Hit enter to continue:";
std::cin >> throwaway_char;
// Hmmmm, does this work?
```

is that if the user enters other garbage e.g. "4.5 - about" it is all too easy to get out of sync and to read what the user wrote the last time before printing the prompt that he needs to see the next time.

If you read every complete line with `std::getline( std::cin, a_string )` and then parse the returned string (e.g. using an istringstream or other technique) it is much easier to keep the printed prompts in sync with reading from std::cin, even in the face of garbled input.

Answer (score 2):

Does cin.[getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline.html) solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

To detect the user pressing the Enter Key rather than entering an integer:

```
char c;
int num;

cin.get(c);               // get a single character
if (c == 10) return 0;    // 10 = ascii linefeed (Enter Key) so exit
else cin.putback(c);      // else put the character back
cin >> num;               // get user input as expected
```

Alternatively:

```
char c;
int num;
c = cin.peek();           // read next character without extracting it
if (c == '\n') return 0;  // linefeed (Enter Key) so exit
cin >> num;               // get user input as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Try unbuffering cin (it's buffered by default).